# What's the difference between [[:upper:]] and [:upper:] (bash)?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, tr

So I'm using bash 3.2.57(1)-release under macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and I am trying to write a bash script that requires case insensitive input. I read that using `tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" <<< "$(echo AaBbCcDd)"` would transform the entire string to lowercase, which it does. However, I had read elsewhere to use `'[[:UPPER:]]'` and `'[[:LOWER:]]'` instead. These still seem to work, but it makes me wonder, is there any difference between these two?

Comment: I think you meant to show `[[:upper:]]` and `[[:lower:]]` because, the ones you have are not valid

Comment: I tested that and you seem to be right. I can't remember where, but I am pretty sure I saw that form as well. I'll leave it as-is but if you feel that it should be changed anyway feel free to do so :-)

Comment: As a side note: `<<< "$(echo AaBbCcDd)"` is unecesarily complicated. Just `<<< AaBbCcDd` has the same effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In regular expressions, `[[:upper:]]` means “any uppercase letters”. But this is an instance of a more general mechanism. The outer brackets `[…]` and the inner bracket-colon `[:…:]` have different meanings. The outer brackets surround a *character set*. Inside a character set, you can use individual characters, ranges like `2-9`, and *character classes* using the bracket-colon syntax. For example, the regular expression `[2-9_[:upper:]]` matches any upper case letter or underscore or digit between 2 and 9.

`tr` replaces individual characters, not regular expressions. (There's another tool to replace regular expressions: sed.) Its argument is a character set, i.e. what you'd put inside the brackets.

```
tr '2-9_[:upper:]' 'X'
```

is equivalent to

```
sed 's/[2-9_[:upper:]]/X/g'
```

You can write something like `tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]'` and it has the same effect as `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`. But that's not because the outer brackets have any special meaning. That's because you're replacing `[` by `[`, uppercase letters by the corresponding lowercase letter, and `]` by `]`. Replacing brackets by themselves has no effect.

(By the way, bash 4 has a built-in case conversion mechanism: `all_uppercase=${var^^}; all_lowercase=${var,,}`. But this doesn't exist in bash 3, which is what Apple provides on macOS. To get bash 4, you'd need a third-party distribution such as Brew.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I had originally seen the `^^` and `,,` and wished I could use that instead. I do have brew but I like to stay stock in regards to bash.

Comment: Hello, while messing about with `sed`, I stumbled across something else just like this. For example, `echo '1A2B3C' | sed 's/[[:upper:]]/_/g'` produces `1_2_3_`, but doing `echo '1A2B3C' | sed 's/[:upper:]/_/g'` prints `1A2B3C` instead. Is there a reason this one is different?

Comment: @leetbacoon In the second one, the first and only `[` starts a character set which goes until `]`. It's equivalent to `s/[:epru]/_/g`. In `/[[:upper:]]/_/g`, the first `[` starts a character set, and in that character set `[:upper:]` (starting at the second `[` in the regex) has its special meaning “any uppercase letter”.